# How to store tick data for diffferent time frames?

Tags: tick-data

I collect data every 30 seconds and store it in a DB. Suppose I want to do analysis for 30m,1H,4H and 1 day time frames, what's the best approach to have access to that data for each TF?

Comment: Welcome to Quantitative Finance! Your question is very difficult or impossible to answer, since it is much too broad. You need to specify many things: What do you mean by "best approach", what kind of DB and what analysis and so on. If you are asking for specific data structures it could even be off-topic and better posted (after sepcification) to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Sorry! Maybe my phrase is not accurate enough. I mostly wanted to know how to choose timestamps based on the selected TF and IMHO  this may dictate how to store tick data. So Now It seems these are 2 distinct question.

Answer (score 2):

Create a separate DB for each time horizon you need in your research.

Comment: A database of End of Day prices normally includes items such as dividends, splits, daily high and low, total day's volume, which are not usually part of a tickdata database. Hence it is best handled as a separate database.